# Migrating Sybase 8 to Sybase 16

Tags: database, sybase, database-migration, sqlanywhere, sybase-asa

I'm hoping this question is appropriate for here, but, I'm running out of options.

I have come across a Sybase 8 database from c. 2000.  I'm being asked to get it up and running; however, even using Sybase Anywhere 16 won't allow me to connect to the .db file.

My experience with Sybase is from a long time ago.  Can anyone suggest or know of a way to get it up and running or even get it upgraded?  Ideally I'd like to export the database and get it out of Sybase and into another DBMS.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Databases from version 9 or older of SQL Anywhere must be reloaded in order to be use with SQL Anywhere 10 or higher. You will need to use the `dbunload` utility to reload the database into a new database and then you can use it with SQL Anywhere 16.

You can do something like: `dbunload -c uid=myuser;pwd=mypassword;dbf=old.db -an new.db` to create a new database from the old one. There are other `dbunload` switches for dealing with page size, encryption, and other options.

*Disclaimer: I work for SAP in SQL Anywhere engineering.*

Comment: Thanks for this. Will give it a try with my dev copy of SQL Anywhere 16 when I get the chance!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I am using SQL Anywhere 17, but I believe you can do the same in Sybase Central 16.